# USO WHERE 1=1 SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

En varios códigos en la web me he encontrado con la siguiente sentencia

```
SELECT *
  FROM <TABLE>
 WHERE 1=1  
   AND ....
```

no logro entender que finalidad tine hacer esta comparación.

Comment: Normalmente se usa para que traiga todo digamos si en tu consulta tienes un parametro como entero un ejemplo y en tu sistema puede o no llegar ese valor si lo mandas entonces filtra por este de lo contrario trae todo y normalmente se pone eso evaluas tu parametro si no 1=1 para traer todo

Comment: [Respuesta respondida en stackoverflow en ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37665646/update-equivalent-of-where-1-1) básicamente lo que indican que lo usan, para poder generar consultas dinámicas.